# Add fonts for offline usage in angular?

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

Angular loads some fonts when starting.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700
```

When I start nodewebkit and I'm offline, it seems that try to load the fonts slows down the app...can I hold this font offline without loading?

Or angular alwasy watch online for this fonts?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure this angualrjs requesting the font and not your own CSS?

Comment: console says line 58 and there is: <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: I don't see this `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700` anywhere in my angular application, maybe you are using some plugin that looks for it?

Comment: I have done a global search...it's bootswatch cosmo theme. I will replace it with path to local font file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not angular's concern. In HTML5 You can use an [appcache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) for that.

as noted in http://www.w3schools.com/

> HTML5 introduces application cache, which means that a web application
>   is cached, and accessible without an internet connection.

create a file beside your `index.html` named `resource.appcache`

add the link to the following files you want to cache inside `resource.appcache`

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.0.0
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700
```

then in your html, link it like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="resource.appcache">
...
</html>
```

Comment: Thx Louie, that means I must have one time internet access to cache the font and than it ever works offline?

Comment: @Loiue Almeda Do you know which line inititates this font call? Or ist it the browser itself? Maybe I have the case that a user never will go online and have only network access to the dataserver.

Comment: I think the manifest works...but I can't see the cahed files in webkit developer tools under resources -> Application Cache? Any idea where they are stored?

Comment: It should be in resources/Application Cache/resource.appcache

Comment: I have updated first post with some pics...there is nothing in appcache...but loading from cache is working. mysterious :D

Comment: Yes, because it works. No, because there is nothing visible in the appcache using developer tools?